# ZarinPal Request not Working In Android 9

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

zarinpal request not working in my app.

I implemented the code as zarinpal documentation, but it does not work.

```
PaymentRequest payment = ZarinPal.getPaymentRequest();


            payment.setMerchantID("71c705f8-bd37-11e6-aa0c-000c295eb8fc");
            payment.setAmount(100);
            payment.setDescription("In App Purchase Test SDK");
            payment.setCallbackURL("app://app");
            payment.setMobile("09355106005");
            payment.setEmail("imannamix@gmail.com");


            ZarinPal.getPurchase(getApplicationContext()).startPayment(payment, new OnCallbackRequestPaymentListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallbackResultPaymentRequest(int status, String authority, Uri paymentGatewayUri, Intent intent) {

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zarinpal work by volley library in android .
volley library version 1.1.0 not working in android 9.
then 
you must update volley library version to 1.1.1

replace

```
implementation 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.8-beta
```

to

```
implementation ('com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.8-beta'){ exclude group: 'com.mcxiaoke.volley', module: 'library' }
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```